# Microsoft Unity causing 30 second delay in app startup

Tags: c#, unity-container

I am using Unity v 2.1.505.2.
On my production Win 7 box, the mere presence of the Unity container will cause the app to delay for 30 seconds before running. Even before I instantiate a container.

```
static void Main()
{
   // a 30 second delay occurs before the next line runs
   DoSomething();
   IUnityContainer container = null;
}
```

Anyone have any clue why this would happen? It does not happen on my development Win 7 box. Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think this is unity? You have other components? I would remove unity refs and check again

Comment: I think it is related to Unity because when I remove or comment out the Unity line, the problem goes away.

Comment: If you use a type in a function and the assembly containing that type is not yet loaded, it would that assembly to load... So you might want to check if more assembly are loaded when the line is present.

Comment: For problems like this use [PerfView](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/PerfView-Tutorial) and capture a trace. If you are having trouble understanding the output of PerfView post the zipped file somewhere online it outputs and put a link in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the following in the config file for the app solved my problem.

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false"/>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```